# Creating Annotations with custom Intellij Plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am very new to IntelliJ Plugin Programming and mainly got to it because my current project requires me create custom method annotations after analyzing the content of my methods.

Is there a way to create an annotation inside like this programmatically?

```
@abc({
  @z("one"),
  @z("two"),
  @z("X"),
  @z.......etc
})
```